# Is it correct to say?

Tags: usage

Which of the following is correct?

> Keep updates of records.
> Keep records updated.
> Keep records up to date.

Comment: "What do I want these candidate statements to mean?". Keeping this question in mind, kindly rephrase your question.

Comment: You can say any of them (assuming you mean 'of' in the first one) - but note that _keep updates of records_ would mean 'keep the new information you put in' rather than 'keep the records in an up-to-date condition', which is presumably what you mean.

Comment: You've mistyped the first example. Did you mean to write *Keep updates **on** records* or *Keep updates **of** records*? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all correct (assuming the first is intended to be: "Keep updates of records." )

Note, though, that they don't mean exactly the same thing.

The first sentence effectively means that you should keep all versions of updated records (or such information as is necessary to recreate all versions).

The second two sentences mean the same thing and it would be hard to simplify further than #3.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant - of not od. 
Thank you very much for the response. 

I would also like to thank Kate Bunting.